Deno.env.get not loading envs from .env file
When I used the dotenv module from the standard library, it worked perfectly fine. However, when I deployed it with Deno, I found out that environment variables were not loading correctly, which resulted in an error. Above, it was recommended to use the Deno.env API instead.
 I followed the advice and tried to use it, but it seems like it's not loading from the .env file.
const uri = Deno.env.get("MONGO_URI");
console.log("URI:", uri); // This returns undefined.

What could be the reason
I wanted to load envs from .env file from Deno.env Api
Update:
for local development, I've added a dotenv to load variables from a .env file and for deployments Deno.env.
let uri;

// Load environment variables from dotenv for local development
export async function loadEnvFromDotenv() {
  const { load } = await import("https://deno.land/std@0.221.0/dotenv/mod.ts");
  const env = await load();
  uri = env["MONGO_URI"];
}

// Conditionally load environment variables based on the "--local" flag
if (Deno.args.includes("--local")) {
  await loadEnvFromDotenv(); // Load variables from dotenv for local development
} else {
  uri = Deno.env.get("MONGO_URI"); // Load variables from Deno.env for deployment
}


Since Deno v1.38, you can load environment variables from a .env file using deno run --env module.ts. (dotenv is not needed for this case.)
It was described in the corresponding version release announcement blog post:

deno run --env
A new unstable --env flag can now be used to specify a .env file to load (ex. --env=.env.dev) or to load the .env file in the current working directory if no value is provided (ex. --env). This has the advantage of not needing --allow-read=.env permissions to load the .env file.
$ cat .env
MY_ENV_VAR="Loaded!"
$ cat main.js
console.log(Deno.env.get("MY_ENV_VAR"));
$ deno run --env main.js
✅ Granted env access to "MY_ENV_VAR".
Loaded!

We’ll be working on improving this in the coming releases to add features such as multi-line variable support.

The argument is also described in the CLI help documentation:
> deno --version
deno 1.42.4 (release, aarch64-apple-darwin)
v8 12.3.219.9
typescript 5.4.3

> deno help run

---snip---

      --env[=<FILE>]
          UNSTABLE: Load environment variables from local file. Only the first
                    environment variable with a given key is used. Existing process
                    environment variables are not overwritten.

---snip---


Denode.env.get retrieves environment variables already loaded, it doesn't load .env files automatically, for that you have to use dotenv
https://docs.deno.com/runtime/manual/basics/env_variables#env-file
The screenshot you posted never mentions that .env is automatically loaded, it only says that you can retrieve environment variables using Deno.env API

Got it,thanks! Deno's Deno.env.get only retrieves loaded environment variables and doesn't automatically load .env files. The documentation suggests using dotenv for loading from .env.

To Automatically load environment variables from a .env file
import "jsr:@std/dotenv/load";
here for more reference
https://jsr.io/@std/dotenv
